# jQuery object - Value = value + number - Doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, numbers, addition

I'm attempting to update a value in an object and set it to the current value + another number. So for instance, if an object's value is `5`, I want it to update like this: object key : current value `(5) + 7`

```
container[response["id"]]["quantity"] += quantity;          
console.log(container[response["id"]].attr("quantity"));
```

This is what I'm currently attempting.. I end up with `57` instead of `12`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get as a string and `+` with `string`s concatenate them. First parse to the number using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` than add.

```
let number = parseInt(container[response["id"]]["quantity"]);
number += quantity;
container[response["id"]]["quantity"] = number;
```

Comment: Didn't work, I'm afraid.. Just end up with 1 - 11 - 111 - 1111 etc.

Comment: I didn't understood. You you provide what you get using 5 + 7

Comment: Ah, yes, just an example :) With 5 + 7, I still get 57 - 577 - 5777 - 5777

Comment: is your quantity a number also? There is one case, one of them is a string. Be sure that both are type of number

Comment: With a little tweaking to my script, this is actually the right solution! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, the value return by `response["id"]]["quantity"]` is a `string`. And when you try to add a number using `+` to a string, then it will concatenate it, something like `5 + 7` is `57`. To deal with this, you have to parse the number to `Int` or to `Float` by using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`. Ex:

```
let num = parseInt(container[response["id"]]["quantity"]);
num += quantity;
container[response["id"]]["quantity"] = num;
```